# Extract vector from list in R

Tags: r, list, sapply

I have been trying to do this for a while but could not reach a solution...

I have one list, say a:

```
> a
[[1]]
[1] 10 30

[[2]]
[1] 15 20

[[3]]
[1] 12 15 30

$[[4]]
[1] 15 30 20
```

I would like to extract the first element, the second and the third to vectors.

I know how to extract the first and second elements:

```
first <- sapply(a, "[[", 1)
second <- sapply(a, "[[", 2)
```

But when trying to extract the third, I get an error, because there is no third element in some vectors from the list.

How could I do this? Should I add a zero to the vectors in the list having  only two values?

Comment: try `sapply(a, tail, 1)`

Comment: @Jimbou that would give them a different result, no?

Comment: @docendodiscimus ah I see. `NA` or `0` if there is no third value.

Comment: When you extract the "third" element what do you want the result to be?

Comment: It would be nice to get zeros `0`, instead of NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this when you want other values than `NA`. Otherwise use the answer of 
@docendo discimus

```
sapply(list(a=1:2,b=1:3), function(x,y){
       if(length(x) < y) 0 else x[y]},3)
a b 
0 3
```

You can also try a tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)
map_int(list(a=1:2,b=1:3), function(x) coalesce(x[3],0L))
a b 
0 3
```

Comment: This function is somehow what I wanted to get. Thanks ! !

Answer (score 4):

Since you're subsetting atomic vectors, you should be using `[`. Then, the result will automatically be NA, when you pick an element that's missing. So the answer is:

```
sapply(a, `[`, 3)
```

Here's an example:

```
a <- list(1:2, 3:4, 5:7, 8:10)
sapply(a, `[`, 3)
# [1] NA NA  7 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to pad the list with `NA`, transpose the list, and unlist the elements of the result

```
lapply(transpose(lapply(a, `length<-`, max(lengths(a)))), unlist)
```

Although in a comment you say you want the padding to be with `0` and not `NA` for some reason.